# Dotted mesh render

Tags: rendering, shaders, effects

How can I create a special shader/render effect where geometry gets rendered - not in wireframe - but in *80's computer*-like dots.

[image: dot render]

Answer (score 3):

You could use **Duplifaces** or **Dupliverts**:

- Create a little dot with an *Emission* material.
- Parent it to the shape (character in your case) you want.
- Select this shape, go in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Duplication*, and click on *Faces* or *Verts*.
- The dots will be displayed on each face or vertice of your shape.

But of course the result will completely depends on your topology

[image]